# Run behat chrome headless (without selenium?)

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, phantomjs, behat, headless

I ran Behat test on PhantomJS without issue. I was starting it with this:

```
bin/phantomjs --webdriver=8643
```

It works, but I want to run a Chrome headless instead of PhantomJS. To do that I tried this:

```
google-chrome --headless --remote-debugging-port=8643
```

But Behat doesn't seem to start anything on this Chrome. I found a lot of docs for Chrome with Selenium but I wanted to know if it's possible to run it like I was running PhantomJS with the Selenium driver, but without Selenium server?

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext
        - Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: 'http://myurl.com/'
      sessions:
        default:
          selenium2:
            wd_host: 'http://localhost:8643'
```

Answer (score 1):

To run your tests on Google Chrome, you will need [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)
Then you can use the port chromedriver is listening to (9515 by default) instead of PhantomJs 8643. You don't need Selenium anymore then.
Finally, you pass the `--headless` flag to chrome so you don't need xfvb.

A config example:

```
# behat.yml
default:
    extensions:
        # ...
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: 'http://myurl.com/'
            sessions:
                default:
                    selenium2:
                        browser: chrome
                        # Note: I'm not totally sure you still need the /wd/hub path
                        wd_host: http://localhost:9515/wd/hub
                        capabilities:
                            chrome:
                                switches:
                                    - "--headless"
```

More documentation: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

- Installed latest version of chromedriver via https://medium.com/caendra-tech/acceptance-tests-with-behat-and-chrome-headless-2824aaa31fd7
- Start chromedriver in the background on default port `chromedriver &`
- Update `behat.yml` to

```
default:    
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      sessions:
        default_session:
          selenium2:
            browser: chrome
            wd_host: http://127.0.0.1:9515
            capabilities:
              chrome:
                switches:
                  - "--headless"
                  - "--disable-gpu"
```